# How computer identify if it is a usb or serial AND what port number to use

Tags: usb, serial, port

Why does external devices connector is in USB type A. But when connected to computer it is listed on com port or either on usb? How do computer I identify this?

Also, With regards to com port. Why do devices differ in com port number? As what I have noticed, when connecting same model of device to same port, they have same port number but when connecting different type of device to the same port, it has different port number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a detailed answer look at the USB specification which you can find [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/).

The simple version:

Everybody making USB devices has VID (Vendor id) which is a 16 bit number you have to buy.

For each product they make they allocate a PID (Product id) which again is a 16 bit number.  Together the uniquely identify a product, each product may also have a serial number but this is not required by the standard.

In USB everything is driven by the host (PC). When you plug the device in your OS asks the device for its VID and PID, if it recognizes these it can just talk to it, if not you are given the opportunity to install the device.

For virtual serial ports Windows uses the serial number, if available, to assign port numbers other OSs may be different.

Answer (score 1):

When connected the USB device transmits information about what type of device it is. This information is called USB descriptors and contains vendor id, product id and device class among others. This is part of the USB specification.

Even a very simple device may have some memory to store and transfer descriptors to the host (PC). A keyboard identifies itself as a human interface device, a hard drive as a mass storage device and so on. The operating system determines what to do with this information. Typically select the correct driver and expose it to other software in a way that makes sense.